# Почему событие вызывается 2 раза?

Tags: javascript

Событие клика вызывает 2 раза.
Событие change вызывается 1 раз, но тольео для первого элемента

```
function toggleCheckbox() {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll('.form-callback-input-checkbox-label');
  list.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert(this)
    });
  });
}

toggleCheckbox();
```

https://codepen.io/Alexxxsander/pen/qBMqeyg

Comment: Я запустил код и у меня по одному разу срабатывает...

Comment: Даже в codepen 2 раза срабатывает, а у вас 1 раз. хм...

Comment: Я там же тыкал. браузер хром. Везде по одному разу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы событие вешаете на весь label, а он триггерит инпут, отсюда 2 срабатывания (label + input).
Решение банальное, вешать клик на input:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.form-callback-input-checkbox-label input');
```

```js
function toggleCheckbox() {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll('.form-callback-input-checkbox-label input');
  list.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert(this)
    });
  });
}

toggleCheckbox();
```

```html
<label for="form-callback-checkbox-input-1" class="form-callback-input-checkbox-label">
  <div class="form-callback-input-checkbox-position">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-input" class="form-callback-input-checkbox-input" id="form-callback-checkbox-input-1">
  </div>
  <span class="form-callback-input-checkbox-name">Тест-день! Получить скидку -30%?</span>
</label>
<label for="form-callback-checkbox-input-2" class="form-callback-input-checkbox-label">
  <div class="form-callback-input-checkbox-position">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-input" class="form-callback-input-checkbox-input" id="form-callback-checkbox-input-2">
  </div>
  <span class="form-callback-input-checkbox-name">Тест-день! Получить скидку -30%?</span>
</label>
```

Comment: А вот кликнуть на лейбл я даже не подумал ))

Comment: А я промазал) и 2 раза вылезло

Comment: Ну круто ) Возможно это и есть проблема с решением. Я просто честно жал на чекбоксы

Comment: Ну решение 50 на 50. Текст лейбла, тоже должен быть как тригер

Comment: @Alexsander лейбл по-дефолту является триггером ипнута... Полностью пример добавил